# php преобразование чисел со степенью

Tags: php, php7

Есть числа со степенью в таком формате 
`2.401E-5` 
Как их можно преобразовать в десятичные числа если степени будут постоянно меняться?

Comment: Степень это `-5`?

Comment: Да, E-5 значит 10^-5

Comment: Тебе нужно посчитать `2.401E-5` и преобразовать в десятичный вид?

Comment: Поступает куча чисел в таком формате и нужно придумать как их преобразовать в нормальный вид (в десятичный вид)

Comment: `echo sprintf('%f', 2.401E-5);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А в чем проблемы?

```
$number = number_format(1.0E-5, 5);
var_dump($number);
```

Без разделителя тысяч:

```
number_format(1.0E-5, 5, '.', '');
```

Если нужно до последней цифры, не равной нулю, то можно как костыль:

```
$number = number_format(1.0E-5, 10);
$number = rtrim($number, '0');
```

Второй аргумент - сколько знаков после запятой

Документация по [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php), она вам понадобится

Comment: Благодарю, но не всегда числа приходят в 10^-5

Comment: @Алексей А какие еще приходят?

Comment: 10^-4, 10^-5, 10^-6,

Comment: @Алексей добавил ;)

Comment: Неплохо. неплохо)